# How to remove DISTINCT from VIEWS query?

Tags: views, 6

Apparently while optimizing Drupal 6 performance, I found that somewhere DISTINCT is getting added into VIEWS query without added by any means like VIEWS UI or hook_views_query_alter.

When tested with devel module, found that the SELECT query getting executed have the DISTINCT clause. I am having VIEW displayed in a block shows latest 10 nodes. VIEWS's Live Preview doesn't show any DISTINCT added in SELECT statement, but same query when executed at front end shows DISTINCT in devel query log.

I am not understanding where its getting added? Is there any way to remove ?

Comment: Check for _just_ `hook_query_alter`, as opposed to hook_views_query_alter.

Comment: I don't find api For D6 hook_query_alter.

Comment: You're right, it wasn't available in D6. There could still be an equivalent hook that I don't recall though. Actually, yes [db_rewrite_sql](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.inc/function/db_rewrite_sql/6).